# Joining the data frames on multiple columns in scala

Tags: scala

We have two data frames here:

```
Table1:
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
Col1|Col2| Col3|Col4 |
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
AB| California|1234| SFO|
AB| Utah|5678| SaltLakeCity|
CD| Nevada|8901| Lasvegas|
CD| Arizona|2345| Pheonix|
EFGH|Washington|0009|Redmond|
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
```

Table2:

```
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
Col1|Col2| Col3|Col4 |
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
AB| California|1234| SFO|
AB| Utah|0000| SaltLakeCity|
CD| Nevada|8901| Lasvegas|
CD| Arizona|2345| Sedona|
EF|Texas|6789|ElPaso|
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+

Expected output:
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
Col1|Col2| Col3|Col4 |Result 
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
AB| California|1234| SFO|Match
AB| Utah|0000| SaltLakeCity|Data in Col3 not matched
CD| Nevada|8901| Lasvegas|Match
CD| Arizona|2345| Sedona| Data in col4 not matched
EF|Texas|6789|ElPaso|Extra row in table2
EFGH|Washington|0009|Redmond| Missing row in Table2
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
```

For the above two tables, wanted to compare both tables and find out if there is a difference between two tables and output the differences.

I have created two dataframes for the tables-

```
    import session.implicits._
    import spark.implicits._
    import spark.sql
    val df1 = sql("select * from table1")
    val df2 = sql("select * from table2")
```

I am very new to Spark,Scala and would appreciate any help on comparing the two tables, the two tables doesn't have a key to join , and returning the differences.

Comment: are they the only data? what about if two columns doesn't match?

Comment: If two columns in a row don't match, the output should return the information that the information didn't match for two columns. If more than two columns don't match then it should return as new row in table 2.